# instasearch with HTML in a field - Algoria Search

Tags: javascript, html, algolia

I am implementing Algoria Search.   I am passing data with HTML in a field to format my output with an icon, color and classes.  The issue is that the HTML is not rendering.  I am outputting by just putting {{AllowFoodTrucks}} in the output template.  I also tried the syntax with \" instead of single quotes, no difference.  Any idea how I can get the fields to output right with HTML in the data.

"PropertyType": "Office Building",
  "BuildingClass": "Class A",
  "BuildingSize": 104260,
  "AllowFoodTrucks": "Events Only",

Comment: Can you share your code, please? Without code, it will take 8-10 cups of coffee to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this.  You simply wrap the values with {{{ vs {{